# Passing array from view to controller using Ajax but, on action, array shows as empty

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am passing an array from view to controller using Ajax but, on action, the array shows empty.

This is my code:

**View**

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
            debugger
             arry = [];
                $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Main/CheckBoxes",
                data: { Values: arr["48","47","46"] },
                success: function () {
                    alert("array: " + arry.join(', '));
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            })


        });
```

Action

```
 public ActionResult array(string[] Values)
      {
          for (int id = 0; id < Values.Length; id++)
          {
              string newID = Values[id];
          }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: `data: { Values: ["48","47","46"] },` and add `traditional: true;`

Comment: and your action method name is `array` and you are calling something else from the client script!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
  jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

$("#btn").click(function () {
            debugger
             arry = [];
                $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Main/CheckBoxes",
                data: { Values:["48","47","46"]},//just edit this line
                success: function () {
                    alert("array: " + arry.join(', '));
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            })


        });
```

Comment: created that array using jquery dynamically and array is created successfully and if I send the array like this( { Values: arry.join(', ') })  arry has values but when I send array like this ( { Values: arry}) its show empty array ?

Comment: data:{ Values: arry}

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some issues regarding how you are sending the data! What is your expectation when you execute this expression `arr["48","47","46"]` ????? That is going to give you `undefined` and that is what you are trying to send!

There are two ways to fix your code. You can send the array in the request body. For this, you need create a JSON string from the array and send that as the `data` property while explicitly specifying the request content-type header value as "application/json". You may use the `JSON.stringify` method to get the JSON string of your js array.

Also, make sure you are making the call to the correct action method. In your question you shared the `array` action method code, but in your client side script you were trying to call a different action method(`Checkboxes)!

This should work.

```
var arry = ["48", "47", "46"];
var url = "@Url.Action("array", "Main")";  // Update your real url here
// If your script is inside the razor view, you can us Url.Action (c#) method

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: url ,
    data: JSON.stringify(arry),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(r) {
        alert("Success");
        console.log(r);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Another option is to send a javascript object with `Values` property (which has the array as the value of it) as the data property value of the `$.ajax` call. Now the request content-type header will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;` and the array will be sent as FormData in the request.

```
var arry = ["48", "47", "46"];

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/Main/array",
    data: { Values: arry },
    success: function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: created that array using jquery dynamically and array is created successfully and if I send the array like this( { Values: arry.join(', ') }) arry has values but when I send array like this ( { Values: arry}) its show empty array ?

Comment: I just tested the second part of solution with MVC5 app, jquery 3.2.1 and it worked for me. Did you try the first solution ?